# Post request throws net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, axios, request

I'm getting this 2 errors when using post request to an API
(Using chrome)

> xhr.js:178 POST *MY_API_URL* net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
>   createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error at
>   createError (createError.js:16) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError
>   (xhr.js:83)

I'm doing a simple POST request
(React code):

```
const postData = async()=>{
    let res = await Axios.post('/terrenos', {'idTerreno':'0'} );
    console.log( res.data );
}
```

And in the API side I just have this for debugging(PHP Code):

```
if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === 'GET'){
    main($_GET);
}else if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === 'POST'){
    echo(json_encode($_POST));
}
```

When I dont send anything in body it works just fine (It returns an empty array)

```
const postData = async()=>{
    let res = await 
    Axios.post('https://gpgpy.000webhostapp.com/papaProject/API/v2/query.php');
    console.log( res.data );
}
```

And when I use postman for the same request it with and without body it works too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same issue using Axios with React and a PHP web service hosted on 000webhost. It works perfectly fine with Postman as well as the vanilla `fetch` function.  Odd, seems to be a compatibility issue between Axios and 000webhost...

My solution was to use `fetch` instead of Axios for my API calls, as I didn't see any particular reason to use Axios in my scenario.
[Here's a good example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/fetch-api/fetch-post.html) on how to use `fetch` with `POST`.

Seems like you asked about it 3 months ago, so I hope you found a solution earlier than I could reply. If you managed to utilize Axios with 000webhost, please share your wisdom

Comment: I actually switched my backend to Node JS to use better services than 000webhost & learning purposes. But I deducted the same, some Axios' default configurations must be incompatible with 000webhost.

Comment: Yeah honestly 000webhost kept disappointing me as well... I later discovered it doesn't even support `PUT` which really sucks. Ended up running a `json-server` locally for the [demo app](https://github.com/Polarts/react-mvvm-example) I made instead of showing it as a live website...

Answer (score 0):

Add slash add the end of the url

```
    const postData = async()=>{
    let res = await Axios.post('/terrenos/', {'idTerreno':'0'} );
    console.log( res.data );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. The solution I found is to enable HTTP/2 on **000webhost**. It **can not be enable** in the free version