# net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR React Axios

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, axios

I have this error:

```
POST https://something.000webhostapp.com/apisomething/something.php net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

I am making a React website and using Axios to try login in my website:

```
axios.post('https://something.000webhostapp.com/apisomething/something.php', sendData)
        .then((response) => {

            Cookies.set('studentID', response.data, {
                expires: 1,
                path: '/',
                sameSite: 'strict'
            });

            if (response.data === 'Invalid') {
                alert('Wrong Credentials');
            } else {
                navigate('/studentDashboard');
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
```

And here is my headers in PHP code in 000webhost

[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS6NH.png)

I dont know what to do. This is happening in all of my browsers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post request throws net::ERR\_HTTP2\_PROTOCOL\_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143574/post-request-throws-neterr-http2-protocol-error)